# ansible call handler with variable from task

Tags: linux, automation, ansible

I want to create a conf file for supervisor and after file creation to "reread" by the supervisor with a handler.

my task:

```
- name: add supervised conf
  sudo: yes
  template: src=default.conf.j2 dest="/etc/supervisor/conf.d/{{item.name}}.conf"
  with_items: "{{supervisorConfs}}"
  notify:
    - task with variable
```

my handler:

```
- name: task with variable
  debug: "{{item}}"
```

any ideas how it could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly- handlers don't take args. However, you could simulate the behavior you want by registering the output from your template loop, then have your handler loop over the results stored in that var, and only operating on the ones that changed. The end result will be the same. It'd look something like:

```
tasks:
  template: src=default.conf.j2 dest="/etc/supervisor/conf.d/{{item.name}}.conf"
  with_items: "{{supervisorConfs}}"
  register: template_out
  notify:
    - my_handler

...

handlers:
- name: my_handler
  debug: msg="{{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ template_out.results | selectattr('changed', 'equalto', true) | list }}"
```

Comment: Note that this uses the selectattr filter and equalto test - you'll need to ensure Ansible has Jinja2 v2.8 or greater for this (```pip install Jinja2 --upgrade``` if you need...).